# Is there any way to reverse normalization of mfcc? I have used CMVN of SpeechPy to normalize the mfcc

Tags: speech, mfcc

Here, I have normalized the mfcc:

```
data_2 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=data_2, n_mfcc=no_mfcc, sr=rate_data_2)
data_2 = speechpy.processing.cmvnw(data_2,win_size=301,variance_normalization=True)
```

I need a way to reverse the normalization.

Comment: If you store the standard deviation before doing the normalization then you can reverse it (see https://speechpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/speechpy/processing.html?highlight=variance_normalization for how this operation is implemented, from there it should not be too hard to multiply by the standard deviation to get the original data back).